# Combine multiple functions in jquery

Tags: jquery

This works:

```
$('h2 a').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('Open', 'Offen')); 
});
```

This doesn't:

```
$('h2 a').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('Open', 'Offen')); 
    $(this).text(text.replace('Answered', 'Beantwortet'));  
});
```

How do I write this to combine multiple functions?

Comment: Because you change the original text and override the previous replacement

Comment: I do not think `Unbeantwortet` means open

Comment: `var text = $(this).text().replace(...).replace(...).replace(...)`

Comment: There are a lot better ways to do translations.

Comment: @AlonEitan and epascarello, you are both correct... the second line in my second function above contained an error. I removed it became a diversion from my actual question.

Comment: @epascarello Yes, I realize that there are better ways to create translations. This is meant to be a dirty workaround for code that I cannot modify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You keep on making your changes to the original `text` string, not the result of the previous replacement.

Do all the replacements on the `text` variable, then store it at the end.

```
$('h2 a').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    text = text.replace('Open', 'Offen'); 
    text = text.replace('Open', 'Unbeantwortet');
    text = text.replace('Answered', 'Beantwortet');  
    $(this).text(text);
});
```

Also, the `text()` function can be given a function. It will iterate over all the selected items and update them with the returned value.

```
$('h2 a').text(function(i, text) {
    text = text.replace('Open', 'Offen'); 
    text = text.replace('Open', 'Unbeantwortet');
    text = text.replace('Answered', 'Beantwortet');  
    return text;
});
```